# Golang function and function variable semantics

Tags: go

Why can't I define a recursive function as a variable? I seem to be able to define arbitrary functions except when they recurse.

This is legal:

```
func f(i int) int {
    if i == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return i * f(i-1)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(f(2))
}
```

This is illegal:

```
var f func(int) int = func(i int) int {
    if i == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return i * f(i-1)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(f(2))
}
```

This is legal and I'm guessing it is just because you can figure out f after initialization:

```
func main() {
    var f *func(int) int;
    t := func(i int) int {
        if i == 0 {
            return 1
        }
        return i * (*f)(i-1)
    }
    f = &t
    fmt.Println((*f)(2))
}
```

So it looks like it comes down to function and variable declarations of a function type are treated differently though from the reading the documentation I wouldn't expect that to be the case. Did I miss the part of the documentation detailing this?

I would expect the illegal case to work just because it works in other languages. Like in JavaScript:

```
(function () {
  var f = function (i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    return i * f(i - 1);
  };

  console.log(f(2));
})();
```

Comment: Go is not Javascript. Javascript looks at your code and says "that looks ok, I don't know what `f` is yet, but I probably will by the time this block is called", and then assigns the function to the variable `f`, and everything is good. Go wants to know what `f` is first before it encounters code that calls it.

Comment: That is what is happening but doesn't really say why. Go doesn't want to know what `f` is if `f` is declared as a function but Go does want to know if `f` is declared as a function type variable. That's what is weird.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The below code would be the preferred way of doing what you describe. Note that you do not have to create an additional variable, nor do you have a *pointer* to a function:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var f func(int) int
    f = func(i int) int {
        if i == 0 {
            return 1
        }
        return i * f(i-1)
    }
    fmt.Println(f(2))
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's a much better working solution. I am hoping for some documentation that points this out. It does seem to be very strange that functions and variables of function types are treated so differently.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: From the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope): *The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.* That means that the `f`identifier is not valid until the value is fully defined. This is why you cannot do in Go what you do in JavaScript.